# iOS date convertor to return proper date

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, timestamp, nsdateformatter

Having a problem with date conversion, I'm pulling a timestamp value from firebase database and try to change it into a Date string.

Below is a struct to convert the Timestamp value into a Date string.

```
struct DateConverter {

private let date : Double?

init(dateToConvert: Double){
    self.date = dateToConvert
}

func convertToString() -> String {

    let cDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(date!))
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm a"
    let dateInString = dateFormatter.string(from: cDate)
    return dateInString
}
```

}

But unfortunately whenever i try to revert the double value the output seem completely wrong. e.g.:

- 1488873726317 (From firebase DB)

After using the custom date converter to convert the Double value into Date string here's the final output.

- 49150/07/14 03:05

The year is messed up already, Am i missing something here ?

Comment: `1488873726317` is a Unix timestamp in  *milliseconds.*

Comment: What was the actual date/time that was input to Firebase?

Comment: @MartinR Got it fixed had to divide it with 1000 first to get seconds ~ Answered by -Ro4ch

Comment: @mechdon From what i have understood from ~ Ro4ch answer is that the server timestamp is in milliseconds so i had to divide it with 1000 first.

Comment: That's what the answer in the linked-to "duplicate" says :)

Comment: @MartinR Yeah you right, thanks any way mate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to divide maybe,

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970:addServerStamp/1000)
```

Comment: Thanks works fine now, How can i convert that date based on timezone ? @Ro4ch